# JavaScript RegEx partial match/return only matched value of one group

Tags: javascript, regex

Let me use one example to explain my question. Let's say we have a RegEx to match a person's title and name, we define RegEx as

```
/(Mr|Mdm|Madam|Ms|Miss|Dr\.?)\s+([A-Z][a-z]+\s){1,4}/gm;
```

And if we match this against a long text

```
I spoke to Mr John Smith and he would like to refer me to Dr Baska
```

the RegEx will return me two matched entries

- *Mr John Smith*
- *Dr Baska*

My question is how to make the string.match (RegEx) return me only an array of names without title?

- *John Smith*
- *Bask*

**UPDATE**

I saw [documentation about group operator () in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses) mentioning remembering group with `\1`, `\2` etc, but not sure syntactically if this can be used for the purpose mentioned above.

Comment: I think this is more related to NLP rather than RegEx...But can be possible with RegEx if you could gather all the possible combination of Titles

Comment: Harpreet, I see your point. I'm just using this as an example to illustrate the problem only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) with [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop to get the names of persons. To get the name, you can use the capturing groups.

```js
var regex = /(Mr|Mdm|Madam|Ms|Miss|Dr)\.?\s+(([A-Z][a-z]+\s?){1,4})/g;
var str = "I spoke to Mr John Smith and he would like to refer me to Dr Baska";

// Declare array to store results
var persons = [];

while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
  // Trim the person name and add in the array
  persons.push(match[2].trim());
}

console.log(persons);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(persons, 0, 2) + '</pre>';
```

I've also made some changes in the RegEx to match and capture names of persons.

[RegEx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQ9fB3/2)

```
/(Mr|Mdm|Madam|Ms|Miss|Dr)\.?\s+((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s?){1,4})/
                          ^^^                             : Made it common for all and optional
                                ^                       ^ : To capture complete name
                                 ^^^             ^^       : Made the non-capturing group and last space optional
```

---

Following regex can also be used with first captured group.

[RegEx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQ9fB3/3)

```
(?:Mr|Mdm|Madam|Ms|Miss|Dr)\.?\s+((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s?){1,4})
```

Comment: Tushar, thanks, this looks quite promising, I have just edited my question to be a bit more specific on the group operator. Could you advise further?

Comment: @Lee yes, the group operator is required in your case to extract the person names. Those can be accessed by `$n` or `\n` notation. The same can be used when the match returns array by `arr[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript regexes don't support lookbehinds. Therefore, you either have to extract the groups or do some processing afterwards:

```
var sentence = 'I spoke to Mr John Smith and he would like to refer me to Dr Baska';
var nameFinder = /(Mr|Mdm|Madam|Ms|Miss|Dr\.?)\s+([A-Z][a-z]+\s?){1,4}/gm;

sentence.match(nameFinder).map(function(name) {
    return name.replace(/^\S+\s/, '').trim();
}); // => ["John Smith", "Baska"]
```

Comment: Use `trim` to remove trailing spaces `str.match(/(?:Mr|Mdm|Madam|Ms|Miss|Dr)\.?\s+((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s?){1,4})/g).map(name => name.replace(/^\S+\s+/, '').trim());`